# eval в javascript. Какие риски?

Tags: javascript

Доброго времени. Начал разбирать код своего сайта и нашел пару файлов js с использованием eval. 
Во всех операциях используется данная  конструкция

```
   textJoin=rezultAjax;

   answer=eval('('+textJoin+')');
   if (answer.error.code==1)
     {
      alert (answer.error.text);
      return;
     }
```

т.е отправляется ajax-запрос (к примеру: обратная связь на сайте) и результат обрабатывается этим eval и, если, код равен 1 , то значит запрос прошел с ошибкой и вылетает алерт .

**вопрос**: в данном случае чем-то опасны эти eval-ы в js? - Если да, то чем именно ?

Comment: Взглянуть бы на всю обработку ajax запроса и методы его вызова.
А так, если это локальные переменные, то скорее всего бояться нечего, потому что из вне к ним доступ не получить, а значит использовать в корыстных целях будет невозможно

Comment: тем что eval может выполнить _любой_ код который получил. Следовательно чтобы его использовать нужно быть уверенным в том кто посылает ответ, и что ответ будет делать не больше того на что вы рассчитываете. Судя по всему не исключено что данный код с eval можно заменить просто на JSON.parse